# It is possible to do hourly log rotation in Winston?

Tags: node.js, winston

Hi i have a requirement from our production team, I need to create the logs hourly, I know that winston support daily, but this doesn't help me.
It is possible to do this?

Answer (score 10):

You can rotate Winston logs hourly. You need to provide hour (`HH`) in date pattern.

Please check the sample code below:

```
var winston     = require ('winston');
var path        = require ('path');

var transports  = [];

transports.push(new winston.transports.DailyRotateFile({
  name: 'file',
  datePattern: '.yyyy-MM-ddTHH',
  filename: path.join("some_path", "log_file_name.log")
}));

var logger = new winston.Logger({transports: transports});

// ... and logging
logger.info("some info log ...", {extraData: 'abc'});
```

File names will be as follows: `log_file_name.log.2013-12-17T16`, `log_file_name.log.2013-12-17T17` etc.

I hope that will help.

Comment: I'm trying to use the DailyRotateFile but I'm getting an error. I would like you to take a look in this question, please. [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35158768/nodejs-logger-winston-transports-dailyrotatefile-is-not-a-function)

Comment: @AndréLuiz, it looks like there was a quite recent change of Winston library (https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) and at the end of November, 2015, `DailyRotateFile` transport has been moved to a separate module `winston-daily-rotate-file`. You just need to add that module to your package.json and `require('winston-daily-rotate-file')`. I will update my answer shortly.

Comment: I have installed the module and it is giving me the same error =/. I'm using express winston

Answer (score 2):

UPDATED
As @Tom has mentioned **rotating Logs has moved out of winston** and loaded if required

`npm install winston-daily-rotate-file`

**Code sample**

```
const winston = require('winston')
require('winston-daily-rotate-file');
const path = require('path');
let transports  = [];
const { createLogger } = winston;
transports.push(
    new winston.transports.DailyRotateFile({
      name: 'file',
      datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD-THH-mm',
      filename: path.join(__dirname, 'rotate_logs', 'log_file.log')
    })
)
var logger = createLogger({ transports: transports })
```

**Full Example if want to test the above code**

```
dataLog(0)
function dataLog(secondsPassed){
    setTimeout(function(){
        let dateNow = new Date();
        logger.info(`seconds passed ${secondsPassed} and Time is ${dateNow}`);
        console.log(`${secondsPassed}`);
        if(dataLog != 130){ //when reaches 130 seconds stops logging
              dataLog(++secondsPassed);
        }
    },1000);
}
```

The result files mentioned in the attached image

[image: Result of rotating logs]

**EXTRA:** I have created winston examples with different use cases, Might be helpful
https://github.com/shivashanmugam/node-lab/blob/master/winston/index.js