# NodeJS Logger: winston.transports.DailyRotateFile is not a function

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I'm writing a rest api with NodeJS and express and I'm using express-winston to log accesses and erros. But I want to separate de log daily. Like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31634652/node-js-express-winston-errorlogger-skip-doesnt-work)

I'm trying to do so with winston.transports.DailyRotateFile. A piece of code below.

```
api.use(expressWinston.logger({
    transports: [
      new winston.transports.DailyRotateFile({
          name: 'file',
          datePattern: '.yyyy-MM-ddTHH',
          filename: path.join(__dirname, "log-access", "log_file.log")
      })
    ]
}));
```

Then I receive the error: winston.transports.DailyRotateFile is not a function

I guess I have to install another pack, since reading winston's doc I found that you can write custom transports.

Would you have information on which package I would have to install? I found some that doesn't match or was discontinued.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to do this so it would work:

```
var winston = require('winston'), expressWinston = require('express-winston');
winston.transports.DailyRotateFile = require('winston-daily-rotate-file');
```

I already had the right [package](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston-daily-rotate-file) but it wouldn't work, until I wrote the lines above.

Answer (score 7):

You do not need to assign:

```
var winston = require('winston'), expressWinston = require('express-winston');
winston.transports.DailyRotateFile = require('winston-daily-rotate-file');
```

You just need to `require` it:

```
const winston = require('winston');
require('winston-daily-rotate-file');
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is [this module](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston-daily-rotate-file).

Just follow the documentation, and you're good to go.